# WP Plugin: Adding a custom code in editing post and rendering it

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new into WP Plugin development. I want to make a plugin which adds the facility to use any custom code within editor to render it into something else. For instance if I am referring my Hacker News profie and I am using the code ***H(HackerNewsID)*** then after publishing it makes a URL of Hacker News pointing to my profile.

What feature of WP would be best fit for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cand try shortcodes http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Thanks. Can I use shortcode API in plugin? If yes then how to do it?